# Does the API do administrative work?

Tags: versionone

I'm looking for a way to do administrative work with VersionOne's API.  Can I add/update/del users in VersionOne via the API?

Permissions is also a desired action.

Comment: Have you checked any of VersionOne's documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes". But there are nuances.

User management has been a popular question lately, so I just wrote [documentation on how to automate the life cycle of users](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Automate_the_life_cycle_of_a_user). Once you know that a user in VersionOne is called a `Member', it is relatively easy to use the standard [rest-1.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData) endpoint to create, read, update, and delete users.

Permissions gets a little tricky. You can set the `DefaultRole` attribute for a `Member`, which is one form of permissions. Then you can also assign a `Member` to a `Scope` (the internal name for a Project), which is another form of permissions. But, currently, you cannot use the API to override the `DefaultRole` for a Project (set the Project Role), as you can do from the UI.

Similar to users, you can also manage Projects (once you know they are `Scope` in the API), Teams, and List Types, as data. There is an API for some of the System Configuration options, but the only "documentation" seems to be code in the API Client. And all of the options for Display Fields are UI only.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond to this.  My account got locked out.